# Avoid using shell commands in perl script

Tags: perl, shell, command

I have this line in my perl script :

```
"$retrieveIps --fields FileserverIPS WHERE Fileserver LIKE '%NET%' | tr \" 
\" \"\n\" | xargs -n1 host";
```

This part of the line above :

```
$retrieveIps --fields FileserverIPS WHERE Fileserver LIKE '%NET%'
```

Should give me this output :

```
NodeName1.comp.com NodeName2.comp.com
```

And I want to avoid using shell commands in my script as much as possible.
I was wondering if there is any way to do the 'tr' , 'xargs' and 'host' command in perl?
I tried to look on the internet but couldn't find anything helpful for me.

This is the required output :

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [gethostbyname](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#gethostbyname-NAME) function to get the IP address and [Socket](http://p3rl.org/Socket)::inet_ntoa to unpack it:

```
use Socket;
my @hostnames
    = `$retrieveIps --fields FileserverIPS WHERE Fileserver LIKE '%NET%' `;
print inet_ntoa(scalar gethostbyname $_), "\n" for @hostnames;
```

`inet_ntoa` is easy to implement (but I'm not sure whether it'd work in Perl 4):

```
sub inet_ntoa {
    my ($ip) = @_;
    return join '.', map ord, split //, $ip
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution , is there any other way to do that? , Since I am not able to use Socket in my company.

Comment: @user3819295: Socket is part of Perl core since 5.0. Are you still running Perl 4?!

Comment: Unfortunately yes , part of our environment still running Perl 4. I will accept this answer since it is answering my question. However, if you could come up with another solution it would be great. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Perl 4 is older than 23 years!

Comment: it Works!! , amazing , thank you so much for your time.